# How to: page with 2 text fields, replace character when hitting button

Tags: text, replace, paste

I'm not a developer myself and even though html and css are kinda familiar to me, php and more advanced languages are not so please bear with me

I want to have a simple html page (or php or whatever is necessary for this case) with 2 text fields and a button

What I want is to paste text into Field 1 and when I hit the Convert button, it will convert certain characters and show it in Field 2.

Example: I paste "I wanna go for a walk in the park" in Field 1. Hit Convert and Field 2 will show me "I w@nn@ go for @ w@lk in the p@rk"

(I know this is a silly example, but just so you can understand what I want to achieve).

I just need it to convert 1 single character at this point, so basically there's only 1 "variable".

Hope it makes and you guys can help me with it.

Thanks and stay safe!
Tiago

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**html file**

```
<input id="input_data" type="text">

<button id="convert">Convert</button>

<div>
      <h1>Output</h1>
      <p id="output"></p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

      document.getElementById("convert").onclick = function(){
            var input = document.getElementById("input_data").value;

            // your choice
            var convert_from = "a";
            var convert_to = "o";
            var finalString = (input.split(convert_from.toUpperCase()).join(convert_to.toUpperCase())).split(convert_from).join(convert_to);
            document.getElementById("output").textContent = finalString;
            copyToClipboard(finalString);
      }

      // You can copy some text to clipboard only by selecting an element
      function copyToClipboard(content){
            // Create a textarea
            var textHolder = document.createElement('textarea');
            // Assign the value
            textHolder.value = content;
            // Appent the textarea to body
            document.body.appendChild(textHolder);
            // "Focus the action" on the textHolder
            textHolder.select();
            textHolder.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*For mobile devices*/
            // Copy the content from selected element
            document.execCommand('copy');
            // Remove the textarea from body
            document.body.removeChild(textHolder);
      }
</script>
```

I hope it helps! ^_&

Comment: Hi Florin. Thanks for the reply 
There are 2 "issues" with that code:
1 - I'm looking for a default conversion, for example, instead of having input fields, I would like to go to the code myself and replace it so I don't have to type the "From" and the "To" every time so let's say I want to convert "a" to "@", for every submission.
2 - I tested your code and it's not assuming individual characters so trying to go from "I need you help" to "O need your help" (if I was replacing "i" with "o" doesn't work. Also, if the letter is part of the word, it doesn't work either.  Hope it makes sense

Comment: I have modified the answer. Let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: YES!!!  It's 99.9% there. How do I make it to work with both small caps and all caps? So for example replacing "a" by "o" would also work if there's "A" that will be replaced by "O". 
Really appreciate your time and help, Florin!!

Comment: It will work in that case as well. No problem, happy to help =D

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working...
Look at this website where I have the code:
http://iam3ple.com/replace/

Use the "text example" I have there and you will see that the A is not being converted to O

Comment: I think i understand now.You want to make these conversions in the same thime: a -> o ; A -> O

Comment: I added an uppercase checker as well. You can see it in the _answer_

Comment: Yeeeeahhh!!! Like a charm!  Again, really appreciate your time and help, Florin!

Comment: Ok just one last question and if this takes forever to write, then it's ok, I will do it manually: is there a way that when I click the Convert button, it automatically copies that converted text to the Clipboard? I found this page, but not sure how to use it along with your code: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp (again, if this is too much work, no worries  )

Comment: Can you create another qusetion, please? I can't rewrite the code here because it will look ugly. O_0

Comment: Or, just add the clipboard requirement in the question header, i will modify my answer 

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that (the question header part)...
I created this Google Docs doc and you can paste it there:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Siu9CzaLSLEEQ6yHDGcaA3J8W3PUgRDa-TJanbKvvXQ/edit?usp=sharing 

Comment: Look at the answer. Use function copyToClipboard(content) 

Comment: Thanks again!  I guess you were able to edit the code, because I marked it back to "unsolved"  
So, I was able to make it work on my laptop, but when I try it on my iPhone, it doesn't copy to clipboard. It converts without any issues, but it doesn't copy to the clipboard... weird... any idea why?

Comment: _https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp_ . I skipped this part: textHolder.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*For mobile devices*/ On android it seem to work without selecting the range :) Let me know if that works.

Comment: It worked like a charm!!! You're the best! Really appreciate all your time and help, Florin! 

Comment: _____________________